# preselect dropdown in angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

i have this form for edit user info :

```
<form [formGroup]="editUSer">
  <input formControlName="name">
<select formControlName="roleName">
  <option *ngFor="let item of listRole">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
</form>
```

use this code for setvalue in form :

```
this.editUSer.setValue({
  name:this.usermodel.name,
  roleName:this.usermodel.roleName
})
```

but i need to set dropdown user value .

for exmaple user have `manager` role but it not set the `manager` in drodown .

[Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odnpuc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedituser%2Fedituser.component.ts)

how can i set value of user in dropdown .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your `usermodel` property, I have realised that it is binded to the `name` of `item` in `listRole`. Therefore, You will need to bind the `value` attribute on your  to the name property of item  (`item.name`).

```
<form [formGroup]="editUSer">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <select formControlName="roleName">
    <option *ngFor="let item of listRole" [value]="item.name">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

As for your component.ts, I don't see any glaring issues. I have edited your demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdmqnc?file=src/app/edituser/edituser.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

Why not bind the selected attribute.

```
<form [formGroup]="editUSer">
  <input formControlName="name">
<select formControlName="roleName">
  <option *ngFor="let item of listRole" [selected]="item.name === roleName">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: If the roleName is present in listRole, it will surely work, the name has to be exactly the way it appears in the listRole Array